# Checking case in multiple case statement

Tags: c#, switch-statement, case

Consider following case statement

```
Case 'A':
     break;
Case 'B':
Case 'C':
     // some logic
     int i = 0;

     // here I need i =5 (if case id 'B')  and i=10 (if case is 'C')

     // Rest of the logic is same
     break;
```

I know I can achieve this by writing seperate case for 'B' and 'C' and writing rest of the logic in a seperate function and call that function in 'B' and 'C' case.

But is there any way, I can check the case in Case statement only ... as follows

```
Case 'B':
Case 'C':
     // Can I check here
     // if (case == 'B')
     //      i = 5;
     // if (case == 'C')
     //      i = 10;
     // Rest of the logic
```

Comment: Use this switch(**variable**) if(**variable** == 'C') ...

Comment: you probably should move the common logic into a method

Comment: Why don't you want to write two separate cases?

Comment: You have once again to do comparison logic with the value of expression used in `switch()`. You then can either use `switch-case`, `if-else`, or ternary operator.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried the following which worked without any problems:

```
switch (a)
{
    case 'A':
        Console.WriteLine("Es ist ein 'A'.");
        break;
    case 'B':
    case 'C':
        if (a == 'B')
            Console.WriteLine("Es ist ein 'B'.");
        if (a == 'C')
            Console.WriteLine("Es ist ein 'C'.");
        break;
}
```

But if you're just checking if it's 'B' or 'C', I would suggest writing two separate cases.

Comment: I had assumed that `a` was some hideously complex expression that they didn't want to repeat and didn't want to place in a separate variable, but since this has been accepted, I must be wrong.

Comment: `char a = 'C';` is not needed though. I was just thinking to check if case is 'B' or 'C'. And the condition `if(a=='B')` does it. So it is the accepted answer. thanks for Help!

Comment: I accidentally added `char a = 'C'` to my answer because I used it to test if the `"case-ifs"` work.

Answer (score 2):

Put your `//Rest of Logic` inside a new method, and do separate test cases for a neater code:

```
private void DoSomething(int i)
{
    //Rest of Logic
}

public void SwitchMethod(char input)
{
    int i = 0;
    Switch (input)
    {
        case 'A': 
            break;
        case 'B':
            i = 5;
            DoSomething(i);
            break;
        case 'C':
            i = 10;
            DoSomething(i);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the obvious solution and the good one. But I was thinking to do it without using different cases.